# Why is NumPy’s "boolean indexing" slower here then "filter"

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a question regarding the speed of NumPy’s boolean indexing: I expected it to be faster then pythons regular filter method. Did I utilized it wrong? Thank you for your help in advance!

```
L = np.arange(499999, 1000000) 
index = (L % 6 == 1) | (L % 3 != 1)
L = L[index]
#9.53 ms ± 370 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

L = range(499999, 1000000)
L = filter(lambda x:(x % 6 == 1) or (x%3 != 1), L)
#338 ns ± 1.13 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each) much much faster!!!

L = [x for x in range(499999, 1000000) if (x % 6 == 1) or (x%3 != 1)]
#51.5 ms ± 1.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each) I expected this to be faster too!?
```

Comment: `filter` is lazy: it does not *do* anything, unless you *iterate* over it.

Answer (score 3):

In [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), `filter` is *lazy*. That means that if you call `filter(lambda x:(x % 6 == 1) or (x%3 != 1), L)`, it will not *do* anything. It will just create a `filter` object, but not filter the iterable at all.

It is only when you *iterate* over that object, that it will start enumerating over the underlying source, and each time try to find the next element of that source that satisfies the given predicate.

So *constructing* a `filter` is done in constant time. If you however use something like `list(..)` that will materialize the list, we obtain for 10 runs:

```
>>> timeit(lambda: list(filter(lambda x:(x % 6 == 1) or (x%3 != 1), L)), number=10)
2.855049993000648
```

so on average, it takes 0.2855 seconds to filter the entire list `L`.

Comment: Right, I should have remembered that, I feel a little stupid now... Thanks!

Comment: Are you timing a `lambda` function? Why not run `timeit(list(filter(lambda x:(x % 6 == 1) or (x%3 != 1), L))`? Just curious

Comment: @Onyambu: because then it will *first* evaluate the `list(..)` filter, and then try to call the list. But a list is not callable (or a string), so that will error, and furthermore, even it was callable, the work would already been done *before* control is passed to the `timeit`.

Comment: well that is new to me. Will have to read more. Funny enough the code I wrote works on my end